# Как сделать скольжение по наклонной в Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу свой контроллер на C#, проблема вся в том, что персонаж идет даже по сильно высоким горам.
Вот код:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward*10*Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward*-10*Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Ужасно. У вас в одну кучу смешаны бизнес-логика (`Application.Quit()`) и UI-часть (обработка клавиатуры). Почитайте про MVC/MVP.

Answer (score 3):

Мне одному казалось, что контроллеры всегда пишутся на физике, а не просто на трансформах?
Юзай `Rigidbody.AddForce()`
и будет тебе счастье
(или просто `Rigidbody` посмотри в  [Unity Script Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Rigidbody))

Comment: Да, я думаю Вам одному :) Для персонажа если это просто человек, а не какая нибудь техника, как раз лучше физику и не использовать, иначе Вам будет очень сложно им управлять. Вы должны управлять объектом или только физикой или только трансформом, иначе это будет жутковато, когда вы добавите ему силу и будете куда нибудь еще перемещать. В unity как раз для персонажей, есть Character controller, он обрабатывает физику не дает провалится или пройти через стену и при этом персонаж перемещается просто мувом, без rigidbody и добавлением силы.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос маленько не корректен. Если вернуться к нашему миру, то что значит гора слишком высокая, что человек наступив на нее должен со скользнуть вниз? Сколько бы человек не шел по горе, он может еще и еще по ней идти, высота горы тут его совсем не остановит. Скорее может ограничить угол наклона горы, если он не имеет соответствующего снаряжения. Если Вы хотите ограничить персонажа в передвижении по горам с определенным наклоном, то это в Unity уже реализовано для Вас. Вы должны добавить Character Controller к своему персонажу, и двигать персонаж им, у него есть метод Move. И он позаботится о всей физике, у него есть параметр Slope Limit это я так полагаю, то что Вам нужно.

[Unity Manual Character Controller](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html)

[Character Controller Move](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html)